# Not able to publish data on aws mqtt broker, its getting stuck at publish after getting connected status 'true' in below code

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, publish

I am trying to connect my NodeJS client to aws mqtt broker.
In below client code i am getting 'connected true'  in response but could not able to publish data.

```
var mqtt    = require('mqtt');

var KEY = fs.readFileSync('xx.key');
var CERT = fs.readFileSync('xx.pem.crt');

var options=
{
clientId:"js111",
rejectUnauthorized : false,
key: KEY,
cert: CERT,
}

var client  = mqtt.connect("mqtts://xx.amazonaws.com:8883",options);

client.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

client.on("connect",function(){ 
console.log("connected  "+ client.connected);

    client.publish('test1', "This is test msg", {qos: 2}, (err) => {
                  if (err) console.log('error occur: ', err);
                  else console.log('message successfully publish');
        });

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are publishing your message with `{qos: 2}`; this is [not supported by AWS IoT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/mqtt.html#mqtt-qos):

> AWS IoT and the AWS IoT Device SDKs support the MQTT Quality of Service (QoS) levels 0 and 1. The MQTT protocol defines a third level of QoS, level 2, but AWS IoT does not support it.

*Note: As you have not provided much detail in your question (error messages etc) this may not be the full issue (but attempting to publish a QOS2 message will result in your connection being dropped).*

Comment: Yes, its worked after removing qos 2, earlier it was stuck at publish.